# How to get muliple files as apache beam input?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Am working on this scenario :
In Google Cloud Storage my files are store in this structure :

PS*: the 2 files are in the same folder (it was an indent mistake)

[image]

what i want to do is:

1] read the 2 files "client_info.csv" + "client_events.csv" from each day

2] join columns based on a common column inside each file to get 1 pcollection

3] doing transformations

4] load data to bigquery

I wrote a code that read only from 1 date and it works well, But i couldn't solve the part of iteration over all dates

if you have any suggestion, please provide it .

Answer (score 1):

A solution may be to consider a pipeline that merges two branches. In each branch you consider one input file separately and then you join them.

Please check out the illustration and the sample code available [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/design-your-pipeline/#multiple-sources)

Comment: so to make it more clear, you mean that reading 2 files from a date, merge them to be considered as one branch input.
the question is that i have 2 years of data, 730 days so i will get 730 branches right?

Comment: Yes, probably it is not the neatest way to do that, but it should be an easy workaround